# Draggable element gets disable after one movement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(this.dom.full).draggable({
    containment: '#gib1',
    disabled: false,
    stop: function(event2, ui) {
        cancelFollow = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have made my div draggable but, it gets disable after one movement. Please help.

Regrads
rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `return false` statement from the `stop` event handler.

```
$('this.dom.full').draggable({
    containment: '#gib1',
    disabled: false,
    stop: function(event2, ui) {
        cancelFollow = true;
    }
});
```

This works.